# Should small numbers with a unit after them be spelt out or written in digits?

Tags: numbers, science

I heard it is better to write out numbers less than ten then to represent them using digits. Is this still true if there's a unit of measurement after the number?

For example, in a research paper where time was being measured would it be expressed as

> five ms

instead of

> 5ms

Comment: You may be thinking of Associated Press style, which is (usually) to spell out numbers from one to nine and use numerals after 10. However, when there is a unit of measure following the number, always use the numeral. So, in your example, *5 ms* would be preferred.

Comment: This is off-topic. You might like to ask on [Writers.SE] instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of thing that style-guides often have precise rules on. Still, if anything a measurement would if anything be a case where digits are particularly useful, if precise (rather than e.g. "it was about 5 millimeters thick" judged just by eyesight) because one is more likely to want to do arithmetic with the numbers than in some other cases, and the decimal system of notation aids arithmetic more than spelling-out numbers does.

Answer (score 0):

The Chicago Manual of Style has what it terms its *general rule* (emphasis mine):

> In nontechnical contexts, Chicago advises **spelling out** whole numbers
>   from zero through one hundred and certain round multiples of those
>   numbers.

Section 9.13, "Physical quantities in general contexts" advises:

> In nontechnical material, physical quantities such as distances,
>   lengths, areas, and so on are usually treated according to the general
>   rule.

However, it goes on to say:

> It is occasionally acceptable to depart from the general rule for
>   certain types of quantities that are **commonly (or more conveniently)
>   expressed as numerals;** such a departure, subject to editorial
>   discretion, must be consistently applied for like quantities across a
>   work.

To summarize, if its customary or convenient in your paper or field of study to express (for example) units of time numerically, then do so; but do so in a consistent manner.

Answer (score 0):

I would never write out the number and abbreviate the unit, ugh. Your choice should be between

> 5 ms

and

> five milliseconds

The written-out form suggests some intentional imprecision. For instance if I were to read in the text of a paper that "measurements were taken every five minutes" but then see later in a data table measurements at 4.8 minutes, 9.6 minutes, 14.6 minutes, 19.4 minutes, I wouldn't be surprised or concerned.

Note that numbers with more than one significant digit ("four point eight minutes") are essentially never written out, even when they're less than ten.